# A quadratic form is positive-definite iff its set of isotropic vectors is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

Considering a quadratic form $Q$ in a finite dimensional vector space $V$ can I say that

$\mathscr{I}=\big\{ \vec{o} \big\} \iff Q $ is  definite positive
?

Where $\mathscr{I}$ is the isotropic vectors set.

Are there cases in which 
$\mathscr{I}=\big\{ \vec{o} \big\}$ and $ Q $ is not positive definite?

Thanks in advice

Comment: The vector space is over $\mathbb{R}$ ? If so,  yes, it can be either positive or negative definite.

Answer (score 2):

As orangeskid points out, the answer is essentially affirmative on real vector spaces, because of [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia).

More precisely, a real quadratic form without isotropic vectors has a sign: it is either positive or negative definite.

This, of course, fails on complex vector spaces, see e.g. $Q(z)=i\lvert z\rvert^2$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

P.S.: Re to rschwieb's asnswer. On complex vector spaces one still has the following property: if a vector $v\ne 0$ exists such that $Q(v)>0$ and a vector $w\ne 0$ exists such that $Q(w)<0$ then there must exist a vector $u\ne 0$ such that $Q(u)=0$. 
(Here $Q(x)=B(x, x)$ and $B$ is a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form).)

Comment: The complex example is not a quadratic form: $Q(iz)=Q(z)\neq i^2Q(z)$ for $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @tomasz: Yeah, it is not specified in the question so I interpreted it as a "sesquilinear form", which is a common abuse of notation in the complex case. A quadratic example would be, obviously, $Q(z)=z^2$.

Answer (score 2):

> can I say that $\mathscr{I}=\big\{ \vec{o} \big\} \iff Q $ is  definite positive?

No: consider the quadratic form on $\Bbb R^2$ given by $Q((x,y))=-x^2-y^2$. There are no isotropic vectors, and it is negative definite.

There is a proposition you can prove to show that without nonzero isotropic vectors, you get a definite form:

If there are vectors $v,w$ such that $Q(v)>0$ and $Q(w)<0$, then there is a nonzero isotropic vector.

Sketch: Convert $Q$ to a bilinear form $B$ such that $B(z,z)=Q(z)$ for all z.

Use Gram-Schmidt to replace $w$ with another negative value vector that is perpendicular to $v$. (The result cannot have a positive Q value.)

Now normalize both by their length so that v has length 1 and w has length -1.  Then $Q(v+w)=B(v+w,v+w)= Q(v)+Q(w)=0$.

V+w can't be zero since the two vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Very nice. This proof works on complex vector spaces as well and shows that if one has vectors of opposite sign then there must exist an isotropic vector.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm not sure how this applies to any complex spaces *with a quadratic form* (since there is no notion of order) unless perhaps you're thinking of a real sesquilinear form(?)

Comment: Yes, I am talking about sesquilinear forms.If you have a positive and a negative vector, then you must also have a null one. (See the Re in my answer)

Comment: Interesting, I've never tried the analogue of quadratic forms for sesquilinear forms. I wonder if the intuition is different for such spaces